# Checking path link in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I want to check the path in React Js.

For example => `/dashboard` and `/dashboard/xyz`

where `xyz` can be any other path.

How can I do it?

I thought of doing `/dashboard/*` but this is not working.

```
const renderdashboard = (pathname === "/dashboard/*") ? ( <Dashboard /> ) : null;
```

Comment: How you are checking? Post your code.

Comment: @ravibagul91 Added the code.

Comment: Can you post complete component to see how you are getting pathname? Are you using `withRouter`?

Comment: is it relative path?

Comment: @GvSharma Yes, its is

Comment: @yfusav don't forget to upvote answers that are useful, and accept one if it solves your problem

Answer (score 3):

You should probably be using [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/).

That being said, React is a display framework and doesn't include any code for this. Use regular Javascript to check it.

Get the location using `window.location` [as described here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location),
then use any string function to compare it.

Examples:

```
window.location.pathname.includes('/dashboard/');
```

```
window.location.pathname.search(/^\/dashboard\/) > -1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/) and other routing library for routing in react.

Optional parameter is easy to create with the help of these libraries.

Below is the example code for your problem using `react-router`

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

function BasicExample() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/dashboard/xyz">Dashboard</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <hr />
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/dashboard/:something?" component={Dashboard} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Home</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

function Dashboard({ match }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Dashboard {match.params.something}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}


export default BasicExample;
```

Hope that helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can test if a string contains another string with a regex:

`/\/dashboard\//.test(pathname) ? renderstuff.. : null`

Note that React itself does not have anything to do with paths, this is more about vanilla javascript and/or a routing library, so check your tags in the future

Answer (score 0):

### path="/dashboard/:xyz?"

You can use react-router-dom npm, and use Route.

```
<Route path="/dashboard/:xyz?" component={Dashboard} />
```

And in the component you can check the params and define state to render something in accordance.

```
componentDidMount() {
    const isXYZ = this.props.match.params.xyz;
    if (xyz) {
      // path = /dashboard/something
    } else {
      // path = /dashboard
    }
  }
```